# What is GET requests in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, storage, amazon-linux

I am being charged for Amazon GET requests - APS3 Requests Tier 2.
Please give me an example if possible what this means exactly.

(is GET that : if any user visits the link of the specific file of S3 Storage?)

Comment: Is it `APS3` instead of `ASPS3`?

Comment: Yes sorry that is only my mistake. Edited now

Answer (score 3):

If it's `APS3 Requests Tier 2`, then it applies to GET and all other non-Tier1 requests to S3 in Asia Pacific (Mumbai) region, and the objects are stored in standard (default) storage class.

Some typical examples that are in this category:

1. You download an object from a Mumbai S3 bucket
2. Some web crawler scans your S3 bucket in Mumbai region and results in a bunch of 403 Access Denied errors
3. Origin fetch requests made by CloudFront